# "Благоустроїти" — це калька з російської?

Tags: вживання-слів, росіянізм

У [Практичному пораднику Т. Вакуленко, Н. Косенко](https://www.bookland.com/kat/books/808446) знаходимо:

> **благоустроїти** — калька з російської
> (хоча є **благоустрій**). В українській мові не вживається.

Однак, знаходжу це слово в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/blaghoustrojity):

> **БЛАГОУСТРО́ЇТИ** див. благоустроювати.
>
> *БЛАГОУСТРО́ЮВАТИ*, юю, юєш, недок., рідко, *БЛАГОУСТРО́ЇТИ,* ою, оїш, док., перех. Добре впорядковувати, забезпечувати всіма вигодами.

Отже, нормативно вживати слово **благоустроїти**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово **«рідко»** у словниковій статті означає «рідковживане». Тобто, це слово фактично вживається, але словник радить робити це з обережністю.

Comment: Чому як вікі-відпис?

Comment: @follower Бо відповідь не містить original research і не є прямою відповіддю на запитання.